# Mysql utf8mb4 equality

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, utf8mb4

I am storing text with emojis in a mysql database.

The database, table and column are set to use `utf8mb4` and `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`.

I can enter the cell values without a problem (datatype is `VARCHAR`).

However, when I try to query the database and differentiate between emoji types, mysql can't differentiate.

For example, if I query the database for the row where `emoji_column = 'hello'` Then it will return all rows that have 'hello' and **any** emoji appended to it (eg: 'hello', 'hello', etc.).

Is this normal behavior? Do I have to compare the Hex values if I want an accurate query? Or is something not set up correctly?

(The emojis are stored correctly, that is, if I query the database by some other parameter, then the correct emoji is returned).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need `COLLATION utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci` to distinguish Emoji.

Comment: Changing the collation didn't seem to help. I found a report of this issue here: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=76553 which suggested the same fix that you did.

Comment: Hmmmm...  What version are you running?  Please show us `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  Let's see `SELECT HEX(emoji_column) FROM tbl WHERE emoji_column = = 'hello'`;

Comment: I don't use the `HEX` function when performing my query. Do I have to?

Comment: This is a different query -- for debugging.